# Redirect wordpress website's subpage to root

Tags: redirect

I have a website, let's call it billyweb.com, built with Wordpress. On the other side, the billyweb.com has a subpage called billyweb.com/blog. I want to move all the contents inside billyweb.com/blog to billyweb.com. My question is how do I redirect all the content links inside billyweb.com/blog?

For example: billyweb.com/blog/what-is-blogging.html redirected to billyweb.com/what-is-blogging.html.

One question again, how to ensure that the redirection works if the old link is clicked through a search engine?

Thanks.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/

Answer (score 1):

you have multiple options to achive this.

The easiest way is to use a redirection plugin like:

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/
```

if you want to work without a additional plugin, 
you can use .htaccess redirection like mentioned earlier:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?blog/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```